# Good books about waves and optics

Tags: optics, waves, resource-recommendations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s a good textbook to learn about waves and oscillations?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15970/whats-a-good-textbook-to-learn-about-waves-and-oscillations)
>   [Where is a good place to learn (classical) optics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21288/where-is-a-good-place-to-learn-classical-optics)

I'm looking for a good book about waves and optics, only basics things and a lot of tricks to solve exercises.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15970/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21288/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favourite is Optics by Hecht and Zajac, though I'm not sure it's still in print. This book wasn't one of those suggested in the two duplicate questions.

Comment: It is still in print! I used during my graduate studies. Very complete and not too formal.

Comment: Everything in optics is still in print. I think Jenkins and white has been the intro text for 100years.

Answer (score 1):

There are two books by Eugene Hecht. The older one was edited in the Schaum collection, with the typical Schaum style: just the minimum theoretical notes, followed by tons of solved exercises. This one is probably what you are looking for.

Another question is the book referenced above, by Hecht and Zajac. Some people love it, some others find it useless. It has lots of written word and many pictures, and it is supposed to cover a huge range of subjects, but with little or no maths. It often tries to substitute a simple formula with several written non-mathematical paragraphs. I find the results not always enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

Anything by Joseph W. Goodman is excellent. His book *Introduction to Fourier Optics* is what I consider the primary book on the subject, and I also own *Statistical Optics*, which I find to be a great reference for all sorts of phenomenon including partial coherence, speckle, and random media.. Note that *Statistical Optics* is **not** an introductory level text.