# How we can study sinusoidal rectilinear motion?

Tags: waves, resource-recommendations, education, oscillators

I don't understand rectilinear sinusoidal motion well, for exemple if I have the time of achieve the end of the trajectory how I can find the period T to calculate Omega? I really need a text book to study it.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15970/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

Just about any material on oscillations will do, in my opinion. [These lectures](https://www.lehman.edu/faculty/anchordoqui/chapter23.pdf), for example, go over many different kinds of linear motion and consider the energy aspect of oscillations as well.

Comment: Is oscillations is the same of sinusoidal rectilinear motion ? I mean in English.

Comment: no, but from your question I figured you where asking about the rectlinear motion with oscillations specifically